# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: npm view npm time --json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I use Node 12.0.0, when I try to npm build I got this error:

```
(node:3968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: npm view npm time --json
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v12.0.0
You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
(node:3968) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3968) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Then build continues. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your version of npm and your version of nodejs are not good to work together. So the message tells you in first part to upgrade node.js. But i suppose you also can downgrade npm version. You can do that with this command : `npm install -g npm@X.X.X` where X.X.X is the version you want.